# Getting the name of a excel file

Tags: c#, excel

Let me first tell that it's the first time I'm doing this.

I'm developing a add-in in c# for excel where a user is suposed to open a file and then press a start button in the add-in to start the all process.

Now, what I want to know is how to get the name of the open file. I don't know where the file is located, so I i can't use FileInfo.

The file name is of this type "Cxxx_Curr_REC_surplus.xls".

I've been trying, but all I get is the name of the active workbook.

I'd like to know if this is possible.

Comment: How is the user opening the file? Manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myExcel;
this.Activate ( );
myExcel = ( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject ( "Excel.Application" )
MessageBox.Show ( myExcel.ActiveWorkbook.FullName ); // gives full path
MessageBox.Show ( myExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Name ); // gives file name
```

Reference:
[How to use Visual C# to automate a running instance of an Office program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126)
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.fullname.aspx)